# Search the details using date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to search the Details using date, it will not work, but searching by name works.

My controller code:

```
public ActionResult ProjectReport(string searchstring)
{
    using (db)
    {
       // var v = db.Projects.ToList();
        var Projects = from p in db.Projects
                       select p;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchstring))
        {
            Projects = Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectTitle.Contains(searchstring));
        }
        var dateFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_3"]);
        if (dateFilter.Contains('~'))
        {
            //Split date range filters with ~
            DateTime = dateFilter.Split('~')[0] == "" ?
            DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(dateFilter.Split('~')[0]);

        }
        return View(Projects.ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this question related to `jquery` ?

Comment: The code needs refactoring. And I cannot understand what you want from the code.

Comment: In this code Project title is working but second if condition date cannot work .

Answer (score 1):

use paramater `DateTime searchDate` instead of using string. Given your column also a date or datetime object, you can filter it right away.

Update: (after looking at your comment)
If ActualSDate in Projects is datetime column. i.e the definition of Projects class is like this

```
public class Projects {
  public DateTime ActualSDate { get; set; }
  //other properties
}
```

in Controller

```
public ActionResult ProjectReport(DateTime searchDate)
{
  var projects = db.Projects
    .Where(c=>c.ActualSDate == searchDate)
    .ToList();
  return View(projects);
}
```

in View
You must make sure there is an input with attribute name "searchDate" and the formatting is in correct date format if this is a HttpPost, or feeding the parameter with correct date format if this is a HttpGet

**Update 2:**
You don't explained why it is not working. Maybe the date string is not match, anyway this is what I did many times in project, minimal version

View

```
@{
  var fromDate = (DateTime)ViewBag.fromDate;
  var toDate = (DateTime)ViewBag.toDate;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Action_Name", "Controller_Name", FormMethod.Get)) {
  <div>From Date: @Html.TextBox("fromDate", string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyy}", fromDate), new { @class = "DatePicker" })</div>
  <div>To Date: @Html.TextBox("toDate", string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyy}", fromDate), new { @class = "DatePicker" })</div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Here, as you can see, I use FormMethod.Get, because this page function as searching page/ report

on master page, my jQuery DatePicker is instantiated like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".DatePicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
     });
  });
 </script>
```

So it will match my written date format like '3 Mar 2015'

In controller

```
public ActionResult ProjectReport(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate)
{
  if (!fromDate.HasValue) fromDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
  if (!toDate.HasValue) toDate = fromDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now.Date).Date.AddDays(1);
  if (toDate < fromDate) toDate = fromDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now.Date).Date.AddDays(1);
  ViewBag.fromDate = fromDate;
  ViewBag.toDate = toDate;

  var projects = db.Projects
    .Where(c=>c.ActualSDate >= fromDate && c.ActualSDate < toDate)
    .ToList();

  return View(projects);
}
```

Comment: public ActionResult ProjectReport(string searchstring, DateTime searchDate)if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDate))
                {
                    Projects = Projects.Where(p => p.ActualSDate.Contains(searchDate));
                }
                return View(Projects.ToList());
            }
        }This also occur error friend

Comment: Dears,  How to set Search Date By (from To)